# redir output of vimrun.exe window to a vim register?

Tags: vim

Using gVim. Please help me redirect output of external `!` commands to a Vim register on my Windows laptop. Here's a specific example:

On my Linux desktop, `!python %` will execute `python file_in_active_buffer` and display the output in a Vim pane. I can capture this output in a Vim register with `redir@a` then "put" it with (normal mode)`"ap`.

On my Windows laptop, `!python %` will execute `python file_in_active_buffer` and display the output in a vimrun.exe window. How can I redir(ect) this output to a Vim buffer?

This is what happens when I try redir on my Windows laptop:

```
# filename test. py
print("this prints on vimrun.exe")

>>> :redir@a
>>> !python %
>>> "ap
"test.py" 
"test.py" 2L, 56C written
"test.py" 2L, 56C written

:!python test.py


-- INSERT ---- INSERT ---- INSERT ---- INSERT --
```

Comment: did you try using redir? if you did what happened?

Comment: Added output when I try redir. Thank you.

Comment: As an alternative, you can use `:read !python myfile.py` to read into a buffer, from which you could do as you please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:redir` capture vim's mesasge, not output of external commands.
If you want to capture that, use `system()`.

```
let output = system(printf('python %s', shellescape(expand('%'))))
```

If you want to read the output in current buffer, use `r!`

```
:r! python %
```